# Difference between TeamIdentifierPrefix and Appidentifierprefix

Tags: ios, app-id, code-signing-entitlements

What is the difference between TeamIdentifierPrefix & Appidentifierprefix. i have an applications entitlements file with icloud(TeamIdentifierPrefix) and keychain(Appidentifierprefix) enabled. i know what is the use of those prefix values in entitlements.

i unzipped the .ipa and inside embeded.mobileprovision i just found both the values under ubiquity container and key chain access to be same i.e, my TeamIdentifierPrefix and Appidentifierprefix are same.

i know that my appid is the Appidentifierprefix, then what is this TeamIdentifierPrefix. can any one help me to understand this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Well, as the names imply, your Team Identifier identifies your team - that is, your (company or personal) identity on the App Store; whereas your App Identifier is unique for a given app. If your team has more than one app, the Team Identifier for all of them are the same, but the App Identifier will be different.

You can view your Team ID on the Apple developer portal (Member Center, under Account Summary.)

The App Identifier *Prefix* is usually the same as your Team Identifier *Prefix* - both are numbers-and-letters combination assigned to you by Apple. The Team ID Prefix (e.g. "1234ABCD") together with the team Id string that you choose for your team (like "com.myteam") identifies your team within the app.

And since the app identifier string usually contains your team identifier string (e.g. "com.myteam.supercoolapp"), this is being prefixed with the App Identifier Prefix (= normally equal to your Team ID Prefix) to uniquely identify your app bundle.

In short: usually there is no difference to you as a developer. Xcode will use the correct one automatically wherever that placeholder (`$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)` etc.) are used.

Comment: U have mentioned "The App Identifier Prefix is usually the same as your Team Identifier Prefix". is there a possibility where they may differ from each other?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know; I could imagine that this could happen if your team ID changes for some reason (which can, AFAIK, only be done by Apple.)

Comment: @IrshadMohamed Yes, there is a circumstance in which your app identifier prefix may differ from your team identifier prefix. I recently ran into this and it's been the source of some entitlement mismatches. If your app was created prior to June 2011, your app ID will be different than your team prefix id. You can contact apple to have it updated. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html